# How to fix django mfa for firefox and safari (Registration Failed as NotAllowedError: CredentialContainer request is not allowed)

Tags: python, django, multi-factor-authentication, fido

I use the mfa library (https://pypi.org/project/mfa/) within my django project.
In Chrome, the user can register a second factor (fido) easily, but in firefox, i get the following error:

`Registration Failed as NotAllowedError: CredentialContainer request is not allowed., try again or Go to Security Home`

I'm googling this since hours but can't find a solution, I already checked CSP Settings. Any help is really appreciated!